# How to use the Operator font with neovim?

Tags: fonts, editor, neovim, italic, terminfo

I am trying to setup my neovim with the operator mono. I am running neovim in iterm2, so I have used the profile preferences to select the Operator font, and that is more or less working.

However I would rather use my vimrc to specify the font for neovim. So my first question is whether that is possible?

Partly, I'd like to do that because I would like to take advantage of the Operator fonts special italics. Normally, I'd activate those for comments in my vimrc like so:

```
highlight Comment gui=italic
highlight Comment cterm=italic
highlight htmlArg gui=italic
highlight htmlArg cterm=italic
```

However, these don't seem to work with neovim. So my second question is: how do I activate Operator italic font for commented out code in neovim.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, terminal vim/neovim use the font-family that's specified in your terminal emulator preferences. So no, you can't specify the font family in your vimrc.

To get italic comments, create a `xterm-256color-italic.terminfo` anywhere on your computer with these contents:

```
 # A xterm-256color based TERMINFO that adds the escape sequences for italic.
xterm-256color-italic|xterm with 256 colors and italic,
  sitm=\E[3m, ritm=\E[23m,
  use=xterm-256color,
```

then do `tic xterm-256color-italic.terminfo` (from the same location as the file). This will create a new `TERMINFO` to be added to the `TERM` database.

Now, to setup iterm2 to use this terminfo, set `Report Terminal Type` under `Terminal` tab of your iterm profile to the value `xterm-256color-italic` (type it manually as it might not show up on the dropdown menu.

[image]

If you relaunch iterm2, you should have italic comments now with `highlight Comment cterm=italic` on your `vimrc`. Verify this with

```
 echo `tput sitm`italics`tput ritm`
```

source: https://alexpearce.me/2014/05/italics-in-iterm2-vim-tmux/#tmux-21-and-above

Comment: only thing is now for reasons that i don't completely understand, when i start and then ssh into one of my vagrants, I'm getting an error on the command line: "open terminal failed: missing or unsuitable terminal: xterm-256color-italic". and many basic things like the backspace key aren't working.

Comment: no worries. it's not ideal, but for the moment, i'm seeing if i can do the same installation of the terminfo into the vagrant guest.